# Расчет стоимости доставки до клиента от ближайшего пункта доставки интернет магазина

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить вопрос. У интернет магазина в городе несколько пунктов , откуда осуществляется доставка до клиентов. Как реализовать функционал расчета стоимости доставки , с помощью яндекс карт, чтобы при оформлении заказа, когда клиент вводит свой адрес доставки,для расчета стоимости доставки (расстояния) определялся ( подставлялся для расчета) ближайший до клиента пункт интернет магазина из которого осуществляется доставка?

Comment: Ну как-как. После получения адреса доставки ищи ближайший пункт и подставляй.

Comment: @Эникейщик  Вот в этом и состоит вопрос, каким образом в API яндекс карт искать ближайший пункт и подставлять его? Если знаете , где можно подробнее почитать , как это реализовать - подскажите, пожалуйста. Буду благодарен.

Comment: Если вопрос в том "каким образом в API яндекс карт искать ближайший пункт и подставлять его", то почему в тексте написано "как реализовать функционал расчета стоимости доставки"? Что у этих вопросов вообще общего? Да и заголовок тоже как связан с проблемой? Чем точнее вопрос, тем больше вероятность получить полезный ответ. PS. С яндекс API незнаком, ничего посоветовать не могу, сорри.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [API Яндекс карты настройка расчета стоимости доставки от ближайшего пункта доставки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862359/api-%d0%af%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: @Эникейщик да я его и создал, где поставил метки,чтобы по профилю смогли помочь