# API Яндекс карты настройка расчета стоимости доставки от ближайшего пункта доставки

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как сделать расчет стоимости доставки в интернет магазине с помощью API Яндекс карт. Есть одна особенность: У интернет магазина несколько пунктов по городу, из которых осуществляется доставка. Поэтому, когда клиент оформляет заказ и вводит свой адрес для доставки, то для расчета стоимости доставки ( для расчета расстояния) необходимо , чтобы автоматически определился ближайший до клиента пункт магазина, из которого будет осуществлена доставка. 
Например,  вот посетитель сайта перешёл в корзине заказа к оформлению своих данных.
Он вводит  ( или указывает на карте) свой адрес. Это будет адрес доставки , "Куда" нужно доставить.
НО! Чтобы мы могли рассчитать стоимость доставки необходимо, чтобы был задан начальный адрес ( "Откуда" везём клиенту). Если бы адрес-"откуда"  был у нас один , то все понятно было бы, что его можно задать и  сделать неизменяемым итд. НО, у нас то 8 адресов ( так называемых офисов из которых осуществляется Доставка до клиентов. Доставляет тот офис , который находится ближе к определенному клиенту). 
Так вот, после того, как клиент ввёл свой адрес( "Куда"), автоматически должен быть установлен в поле "Откуда" адрес ближайшего к нему офиса, откуда будет осуществляться Доставка, чтобы в конечном итоге рассчитать стоимость доставки.
Таким образом, процедура выполняет следующую функцию:
После того, как клиент ввёл свой адрес, "Куда" нужна Доставка, программа автоматически сравнивает расстояние от каждого нашего офиса до адреса, который ввёл клиент. И тот офис , расстояние( маршрут) от которого до адреса клиента наименьшее и должен быть выбран и установлен автоматически для расчета стоимости доставки на Яндекс карте.
Посмотрите, пожалуйста, может где-то подобное встречали? Может подскажете, как это сделать?Где почитать, посмотреть можно?
Заранее спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

У API Карт есть [API Матрицы маршрутов](https://tech.yandex.ru/routing/distance_matrix/?from=SO). Этот сервис как раз позволяет решать логистические задачи и оптимизировать доставку, как вы описали.

Answer (score 0):

Вот два подхода:

1. Считаете 8 расстояний (роутером Яндекс.Карт), выбирайте наименьшее (лучше по времени доставки, Яндекс вродедаже считает с учетом пробок) и вот вам результат. Такой подход потребует больше запросов к роутеру
2. Заранее определите 8 полигонов в пределах которых Вы обслуживаете тем или иным офисом. Затем при вводе адреса доставки определяете геокодером координаты и смотрите в какой полигон они попадают. Соответственно определяете офис доставки.